# Calculus linearization have work can't figure out the last part

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{-7}{86\sqrt{43}}(x-6)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{43}}$$

$$=\frac{-7}{86\sqrt{43}}(x)+\frac{64}{43\sqrt{43}}$$

How did the first answer change to the second answer?

Comment: pls use LaTeX in your questions

Answer (score 1):

Just try writing it out.
$$-\frac{7(x-6)}{86\sqrt{43}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{43}}$$
$$=-\frac{7x}{86\sqrt{43}}+\frac{42}{86\sqrt{43}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{43}}$$
$$=-\frac{7x}{86\sqrt{43}}+\frac{21+43}{43\sqrt{43}}$$
$$=-\frac{7x}{86\sqrt{43}}+\frac{64}{43\sqrt{43}}$$